# Размер мобильной версии сайта как десктопной

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте , очень интересует вопрос , как задать правило , чтобы при открытии сайта с определенного разрешения либо через @Media , либо через meta viewport , отображалась сразу полная версия сайта на весь экран , я дизайн адаптировал, но вот открывается он сначала на половину и только после того как пальцами экран отдалишь показывается вся часть.
Есть ли идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы "включить" ваш адаптивный дизайн, необходим этот meta-тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополнительно к ответу VenZell. Используйте указание размеров в %, а не статичных, например как px.